# Get integer value from string in swift

Tags: swift, swift2

So I can do this:

```
var stringNumb: NSString = "1357"

var someNumb: CInt = stringNumb.intValue
```

But I can't find the way to do it w/ a `String`.  I'd like to do something like:

```
var stringNumb: String = "1357"

var someNumb: Int = Int(stringNumb)
```

This doesn't work either:

```
var someNumbAlt: Int = myString.integerValue
```

Comment: `var someNumb: Int? = Int(stringNumb)` or `var someNumb = Int(stringNumb)`

Comment: Note that integerValue cleans dirty strings, if needed. For example these strings all result in 1357: "00001357", "   1357  ", "+   1357", "1357.02", "1357 Main St"

Answer (score 183, accepted):

**Swift 2.0** you can initialize Integer using constructor

```
var stringNumber = "1234"
var numberFromString = Int(stringNumber)
```

Comment: As of Swift 2.0 you no longer have the `toInt()` method as part of `String`. So this `Int` constructor is now the only way to convert strings to ints.

Comment: The semicolon is not necessary

Comment: Can you please tell how to handle if the user enters number more than an Int64 limit number in the text field

Comment: @Sebastian isn't that frustrating? :)

Answer (score 94):

I'd use:

```
var stringNumber = "1234"
var numberFromString = stringNumber.toInt()
println(numberFromString)
```

Note `toInt()`:

> If the string represents an integer that fits into an Int, returns the corresponding integer.

Comment: This worked, although if you declare the var explicitly, you need to add an exclamation point: `var someNumb: Int = stringNumber.toInt()!` as @NateCook pointed out

Comment: I'm not declaring it explicitly. The compiler knows that numberFromString should be an int because it's initialised as one...

Comment: I know that you are not, but I am.  I had to make that adjustment to do so.  Your code is correct, just adding it as a comment.

Comment: Yes it only returns a value if the value fits into an Int as the note points out. Otherwise it returns nil...

Comment: Ahh I see, sorry misunderstood. There's no need for you to explicitly declare it ?

Comment: I know there's no need, I'm just experimenting w/ different stuff while I'm learning :)

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah It's good to experiment. Been playing with it myself. I really like it. Bye Bye Obj-C.

Comment: Instead of putting `!` on the call, you can declare your variable as optional: `someNumb: Int? = stringNumber.toInt()`. Then the type safety system will be aware that `foo` may not exist. Putting `!` will of course crash if your string can't convert to a number.

Comment: @gwcoffey that's correct, if you leave the ! or ? our and don't implicitly cast it it just returns nil with an invalid int i.e. "wqeqweq". But you're correct that if you add ! after toInt() it will crash at runtime. Also putting ? at the end prevents the crash.

Comment: I'm guessing you would only use var numberFromString : Int = XXX in the event that the initialising operation was returning 'AnyObject'?

Comment: it says **'toInt()' is unavailable: Use Int() initializer**

Answer (score 18):

**In Swift 3.0**

**Type 1: Convert NSString to String**

```
    let stringNumb:NSString = "1357"
    let someNumb = Int(stringNumb as String) // 1357 as integer
```

**Type 2: If the String has Integer only**

```
    let stringNumb = "1357"
    let someNumb = Int(stringNumb) // 1357 as integer
```

**Type 3: If the String has Float value**

```
    let stringNumb = "13.57"
    if let stringToFloat = Float(stringNumb){
        let someNumb = Int(stringToFloat)// 13 as Integer
    }else{
       //do something if the stringNumb not have digit only. (i.e.,) let stringNumb = "13er4"
    }
```

Comment: The code for "Type 3" is not ideal. Instead of checking of `stringToFloat` is `!= nil`, you should use `if let`.

Answer (score 11):

The method you want is `toInt()` -- you have to be a little careful, since the `toInt()` returns an optional Int.

```
let stringNumber = "1234"
let numberFromString = stringNumber.toInt()
// numberFromString is of type Int? with value 1234

let notANumber = "Uh oh"
let wontBeANumber = notANumber.toInt()
// wontBeANumber is of type Int? with value nil
```

Comment: but similarly, `toInt()` is the Right Way to do it. optionals are a core part of the language

Comment: Of course, you just have to be aware that you're working with an optional, not a straight Int.

Answer (score 6):

If you are able to use a `NSString` only.

It's pretty similar to objective-c. All the data type are there but require the `as NSString` addition

```
    var x = "400.0" as NSString 

    x.floatValue //string to float
    x.doubleValue // to double
    x.boolValue // to bool
    x.integerValue // to integer
    x.intValue // to int
```

Also we have an `toInt()` function added See Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l page 49

```
x.toInt()
```

Comment: forgot to add the `as NSString`. fixed it @gwcoffey

Comment: I don't want to use NSString, see question.

Answer (score 4):

above answer didnt help me as my string value was "700.00"

with **Swift 2.2** this works for me

```
let myString = "700.00"
let myInt = (myString as NSString).integerValue
```

I passed myInt to NSFormatterClass

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

let priceValue = formatter.stringFromNumber(myInt!)!

//Now priceValue is ₹ 700
```

Thanks to [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int) blog post.

Comment: This question is about getting an *integer* from a String. In your case, you don't have an Int, you have a Double. In Swift, just use `Double()` the same way we're using `Int()`. No need to use bridging to NSString.

Comment: Hey @EricD thanks for your suggestion but  "**I wanted Integer only**  as I am passing Int to NSNumberFormatter class for currency convertor".

Comment: Well in this case you can use `Double()` *then* use `Int()`. Like this: `if let d = Double("700.00") { let i = Int(d); print (i) }` :)

Answer (score 3):

You can bridge from String to NSString and convert from CInt to Int like this:

```
var myint: Int = Int(stringNumb.bridgeToObjectiveC().intValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension for that purpose. It always returns an `Int`. If the string does not fit into an `Int`, 0 is returned.

```
extension String {
    func toTypeSafeInt() -> Int {
        if let safeInt = self.toInt() {
            return safeInt
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be written more succinctly as `return self.toInt() ?? 0`. It's probably better to just write it that way inline rather than having an extension method for this.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
extension String {
    func getIntegerValue() -> String {
        let value = self
        let okayChars : Set<Character> =
        Set("1234567890")
        let output = String(value.filter {okayChars.contains($0)})
        print(output)
        return output
    }
}
```

Usage & outPut

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
      print("8abc2214ma3".getIntegerValue())
      print("9abc714ma3".getIntegerValue())
      print("7abc5514ma3".getIntegerValue())
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution could be a extension

```
extension String {
    var toFloat:Float {
        return Float(self.bridgeToObjectiveC().floatValue)
    }
    var toDouble:Double {
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

this for example extends the swift native String object by toFloat

Answer (score 0):

Convert String to Int in Swift 2.0:

```
var str:NSString = Data as! NSString
var cont:Int = str.integerValue
```

use `.integerValue or intValue for Int32`

Answer (score 0):

**8:1 Odds**(*)

```
var stringNumb: String = "1357"
var someNumb = Int(stringNumb)
```

or

```
var stringNumb: String = "1357"
var someNumb:Int? = Int(stringNumb)
```

`Int(String)` returns an optional `Int?`, not an `Int`.

---

**Safe use: do not explicitly unwrap**

```
let unwrapped:Int = Int(stringNumb) ?? 0
```

or

```
if let stringNumb:Int = stringNumb { ... }
```

(*) *None of the answers actually addressed why `var someNumb: Int = Int(stringNumb)` was not working.*

Comment: Thank you @user3441734. I should not have used *casting*.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple but dirty way**

```
// Swift 1.2
if let intValue = "42".toInt() {
    let number1 = NSNumber(integer:intValue)
}
// Swift 2.0
let number2 = Int(stringNumber)

// Using NSNumber
let number3 = NSNumber(float:("42.42" as NSString).floatValue)
```

**The extension-way**

This is better, really, because it'll play nicely with locales and decimals.

```
extension String {

    var numberValue:NSNumber? {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
        return formatter.numberFromString(self)
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do:

```
let someFloat = "42.42".numberValue
let someInt = "42".numberValue
```