# Convert string to int swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build a calculator in swift, but it does not seem to work. I don't really know how to explain it but here is an example: If I sum up 1 + 2 it returns 12 instead of 3.

Here is my code. Please note that `num1` is the first part of the operation and `num2` the second.

```
var num1 : String = ""
var num2 : String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) { 
    var currentnumber = self.label.text
    var sendertag = String(sender.tag)
    self.label.text = currentnumber! + sendertag
}

@IBAction func sum(sender: UIButton) {    
    num1 = self.label.text!
    self.label.text = ""
}

@IBAction func enter(sender: UIButton) {
    num2 = self.label.text!

    num1.toInt()
    num2.toInt()

    self.label.text = num1 + num2
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get number value from string in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019236/get-number-value-from-string-in-swift)

Comment: @user3457759 thanks for the reply to all of you. Your code sounds reasonable but it still marks an error. it says to delete the exclamation marks but if i do that then it says that binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two int operants. Sorry for this i am completely new to Swift. Thanks

Comment: @anhtu thanks for the reply. When i execute the code it marks an error:  binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two int operants

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you're trying to sum integers but you're actually appending String since when you do

```
self.label.text = currentnumber! + sendertag
```

Both are Strings (you can check the type on Xcode).

What you want to do is add this two numbers so you have to parse them to Integer, you can achieve this by doing the following

```
self.label.text = String(Int(current number!)! + Int(sendertag)!)
```

This is, first parsing to Integer both string and adding them up and then parse the result back to string because the text of the label has to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign sum of two integer numbers into string value, It may implicitly type casting from Int to String

Replace

```
  self.label.text = num1 + num2
```

with

```
var result: Int =num1+num2
self.label.text=String(result)
```

In objective c it shows up error: Xcode 4.2 or higher

**Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC**