# Convert input data to Integer in Swift

Tags: swift

First, input data using keyboard:

```
    var fh = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()

    println("Please input first number")
    let num1 = fh.availableData
    println("Please input second number")
    let num2 = fh.availableData
```

After accept the keyboard input, I want to calculate

```
    num1+num2
```

and print out. But I don't know how to convert num1, num2 to Integer.

Comment: `println` ? Are you still using Xcode 6?

Answer (score 2):

It depends which swift you are using, you can see how to do it for 1.x and 2.0:
[Get integer value from string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019236/get-integer-value-from-string-in-swift)
In 2.0 you can initialize an int with a string:

```
var stringNumber = "1234"
var numberFromString = Int(stringNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

To print it out do it like `print("My result: \(num1 + num2)")`

Answer (score 0):

The type that NSFileHandle gives you for `num1` and `num2` is NSData.

You can't do math on NSData, you have to first convert the data to numbers.

To transform this data into integers, we're doing two steps: first convert the data to an NSString, then convert the string to an Integer. After that, we can sum the two values.

We're using the `integerValue` method of `NSString`:

```
let fh = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
print("Please input first number")
let num1 = fh.availableData
print("Please input second number")
let num2 = fh.availableData
if let  numString1 = NSString(data: num1, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding),
        numString2 = NSString(data: num2, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    let val1 = numString1.integerValue
    let val2 = numString2.integerValue
    print("\(val1) + \(val2) = \(val1 + val2)")
}
```

Result:

> Please input first number
>   33
>   Please input second number
>   42
>   33 + 42 = 75

Comment: I tried to arrange your code, but I got an error, would you please tell me the reason?
    let  numString1 = NSString(data: num1, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let numString2 = NSString(data: num2, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
if(numString1 != nil)&&(numString2 != nil){
    let val1 = numString1.integerValue
    let val2 = numString2.integerValue
    print("\(val1) + \(val2) = \(val1 + val2)")
}

Comment: My example works. Your modifications make it not work anymore. Observe the differences and you'll know the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did in latest version of Swift:

`

```
class Input2 {
    func inputString() -> String {
        let keyboard = FileHandle.standardInput
        let inputData = keyboard.availableData
        return String(data: inputData, encoding: .utf8)!
    }

    func inputInt() -> Int {
        let keyboard = FileHandle.standardInput
        let inputData = keyboard.availableData
        let str = String(data: inputData, encoding: .utf8)!
        let i = Int(str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ""))!
        return i
    }
}

var inp = Input2()
print("Please enter your name")
var name:String = inp.inputString()
print("line: \(name)")
//var i = Int(name.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ""))!
print("Enter a number:")
var i = inp.inputInt()
print(i)
```

`

Answer (score -1):

You can print or store the sum by :

```
var fh = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
print("Please input first number")
let data1 = fh.availableData
let stringvalue1 = NSString(data: data1, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as!    String // getting as string value
let num1 = Int(stringvalue1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n",    withString: ""))! // converting string to Int
print("Please input second number")
let data2 = fh.availableData
let stringvalue2 = NSString(data: data2, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
let num2 = Int(stringvalue2.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: ""))!
let sum = num1 + num2
print("sum is \(sum)")
```

Comment: @MartinR sorry. I just thought it may work. I didn't compiled before. Now I compiled and changed my answer with working code. Thanks you.