# Convert String Values From Server Formatted as Double To Int

Tags: swift, int

Im working with a service that send back values of type `String` which contains floating point like `Double` as so for example "1240.86".
I want to cast it to `Int` and when i try to convert like so `Int(stringObject)` the cast fails when the values have floating points.
How can i cast it?
Thanks!

Comment: just a note, that is not casting but converting. Have you tried *converting* the string to a double and go from there?

Comment: Thats my solution now but i was looking for more elegant way

Comment: Try Here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39658447/6479530

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it in two steps:

```
if let aDouble = Double(someString) {
    let someInt = Int(aDouble)
}
```

or possibly:

```
let someInt = Int(Double(someString) ?? 0)
```

though the latter is a bit of a kludge since you probably don't want to force a value of `0` if the string isn't a valid number.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't go with the latter because it is impossible to distinguish a string `"0"` from an invalid number.

Comment: I would also add `let someInt = Int(round(aDouble))` as option

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev Whether the `Double` should be rounded or not is a separate decision and not really important to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) method of `Optional` to optionally chain a conversion (initialization by, specifically) from `String` to `Double` followed by one from `Double` to `Int` and conditionally bind the resulting integer in case it is not `nil` (i.e. successfully converted):

```
let str = "1240.86"
if let number = Double(str).map(Int.init) {
    // number is of type Int and, in this example, of value 1240
}
```

Comment: @down voter: consider giving feedback rather than a drive-by down vote. Or is this just an anger down vote ...?

Comment: I didn't know about the `Optional map` function. I like this.

Comment: @rmaddy most of the time its use cases can be replaced simply by optional chaining, but for cases such as this one it can be a good approach. Also note that there's a `flatMap(_:)` method of `Optional` which can also sometimes be of use (passes the single argument as an optional without unwrapping it).

Answer (score 0):

You can separate string by dot `.`:

```
func printInt(from str: String) {
    let intValue = Int(str.components(separatedBy: ".")[0]) ?? 0
    print(intValue)
}

printInt(from: "1234.56")   // 1234
printInt(from: "1234")      // 1234
printInt(from: "0.54")      // 0
printInt(from: ".54")       // 0
printInt(from: "abc")       // 0
```